# Angular 6 Media Query issue

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I am working on an Angular 6 website. I have a component named `our-work.ts`,
I am defining its media query globally in a file `global.scss` just like this,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .pull-custom-left {
    float: none;
  }
  .popular-work .img-section .hovereffect a, .popular-work .img-section .hovereffect p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

other styles than media query are working fine in a component, but a media query is not working.
This is my our-work component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-our-works',
  templateUrl: './our-works-talk.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./our-works-talk.component.scss'],

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the file `global.scss` to your `angular.json` file.

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/global.scss"
],
```

Comment: still same issue, no effect

Comment: Then the issue is not clear to me. Can you try reproducing the behavior in a stackblitz?